# Failed to transfer data from GCS to Bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

Need Help in DTS.

After creating a table "allorders" with autodetect schema, I created a data transfer service. But when I ran the DTS I'm getting an error. see Job below. quantity field type is for sure set to integer and all the data in the said field are whole numbers.

> Job bqts_602c3b1a-0000-24db-ba34-30fd38139ad0 (table allorders) failed
> with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error while reading data, error message:
> Could not parse 'quantity' as INT64 for field quantity (position 14)
> starting at location 0 with message 'Unable to parse'; JobID:
> 956421367065:bqts_602c3b1a-0000-24db-ba34-30fd38139ad0

When I recreated a table and set all fields to type string. It worked fine. see Job below

> Job bqts_607cef13-0000-2791-8888-001a114b79a8 (table allorders)
> completed successfully. Number of records: 56017, with errors: 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find unparseable values in the table with all string fileds:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dataset.table
WHERE SAFE_CAST(value AS INT64) IS NULL;
```

Comment: hey this made me realize one thing.. thanks for helping! :D Header rows to skip should be 1. It's working now!